# Drupal displays title (but no other data) from deleted content-type

Tags: drupal

My http://drupal.94y.info/ Drupal 6 install displays the titles of many nodes from a 
content-type that no longer exists.

When I deleted the content-type, Drupal deleted the data in those 
nodes, except for the title which apparently still remains.

How to fix?

For admin access, gmail chat me carter.barry@gmail.com

Comment: Assuming you're using a view, you might have it configured wrong... otherwise it might be a performance measure gone awry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the title is a core field (stored in the tables "**node**" and "**node_revisions**"). The other data are stored in another table "**content_type_NAMEOFTYPE**" (plus additional tables per field that accepts multiple values).

When you delete a Content Type, **it only deletes the extra table(s), but the contents inside "node" and "node_revisions" remain**, therefore you end up with incomplete nodes because only the title (and the body/teaser) remain in the database, the rest has been erased with the table (which is a design inconsistency imho, they should truly delete any node that uses the content type that you delete instead of simply deleting the extra table(s)).

---

The most straightforward way to fix that is to delete the rows directly in the database (table "**node**" stores the name of the content type in field "**type**" so it's easy to find the faulty rows, just don't forget to also delete the matching rows in **node_revisions** as well), then clear the cache in "Drupal > Admin > Performance".

But don't do that unless you make a database backup first, just in case ;-)

Comment: Shortly after I asked, the nodes magically showed up under "Content Management", and I deleted them one page at a time (odd that you can't delete all nodes matching a criteria at once.. limited to about 25 nodes at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't delete nodes of a content type when you delete the content type. I believe that's by design, and you're expected to delete the nodes yourself if that's what you want to happen. If you don't have too many nodes, you can do this either with the default content edit admin screen. If that's too tedious, [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) is a good way to do it. You could also do a form_alter on the content type form and make this happen automatically, but that's only worth exploring if this is a situation you encounter often.

Comment: I'll try View Bulk Operations. These nodes don't show up on my content edit admin screen. Also, Drupal warned me that deleting the content-type would delete 'all 1622 nodes' with this content-type. Lies?

Comment: Because those nodes no longer have types, and thus, you cannot filter out by (blank) node type. You can create a dummy type, then run a SQL query to assign that node type to nodes with no type assigned, come back to the content admin screen, filter by your dummy type, then run the delete. That would work.